# Fscanf and Strings

Tags: c

So I have to use fscanf for a scanning a paragraph (of words) in a text file and have written the following code and it should work in theory, but it does not I would really appreciate any help.

Code snippet:

```
 char foo[81];
 char *final[MAXIUM]; //this is another way of making a 2d array right?
 int counter=0; 

 while (counter<MAXIUM && fscanf(file, "%s", foo)!= EOF){ 
   *final = (char*)malloc(strlen(foo)*sizeof(foo)); 
   //if (final ==NULL) 
   *(final + counter ) = foo + counter;

   counter++;
 }
```

The text file looks like any old paragraph:

However the company is yet to respond to their customer’s social media queries. You could be an avid social media enthusiast or a fan of it.

---

The main point of this bit of of code is to scan the paragraph from a text file using %s and fscanf ONLY then allocating enough space for each word and putting it in final (foo is temporary just for the scanning bit, it has to be done this way) We know the maximum words read through MAXIUM.

Thanks for all your help:

Comment: what error did you get in trying to execute it ?

Comment: No error, but when printing out word using for(counter=0; i<MAXIMUM; counter++)  printf("%s",final[counter]); I just get garbage.

Comment: `fscanf(foo, "%s", foo)` ?

Comment: oh oops, the first one is just a random file name, but that's not the problem

Comment: *final = (char*)malloc(strlen(foo)*sizeof(foo)); 
   //if (final ==NULL) 
   *(final + counter ) = foo + counter; ...there is a problem here i think ..... also you have nothing to put a null char at the end to complete the string

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while (counter<MAXIUM && fscanf(foo, "%s", foo)!= EOF){
  *final = (char*)malloc(strlen(foo)*sizeof(foo)); 
  *(final + counter ) = foo + counter;
....
 for(counter=0; i<MAXIMUM; counter++) printf("%s",final[counter])
```

to

```
// Also recommend that the first thing you do is fill your `final[]` with NULL, 0
for (int j=0; j<MAXIUM; j++) final[j] = 0;

// changed fscanf to fgets.  Less issues with dropping whitespace.
while ((counter<MAXIUM) && (fgets(foo, sizeof(foo), stdin)!= EOF)){ 
  final[counter] = (char*)malloc(strlen(foo)+1);  // some say (char*) cast is undesirable, bit allowed.
  strcpy(final[counter], foo);
  // eliminate *(final + counter ) = foo + counter;  
...
for(i=0; i<counter; i++) printf("%s",final[i]);  // The fgets() will preserve the EOL
```

Comment: Could use `strdup(foo)` instead of `(char*)malloc(strlen(foo)+1)`and strcpy()

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be change the code, for correct the output mass

```
 while (counter<MAXIUM && fscanf(foo, "%s", foo)!= EOF){ 

   /* the  strlen(foo) + 1 for store '\0' */
   final + counter = (char*)malloc((strlen(foo) + 1)*sizeof(foo)); 
   /* to copy the "foo" content  to final + n */
   strcpy(final + counter, foo, strlen(foo));
   /* each time should clear the foo array */
   memset(foo, 0, 81);

   counter++;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think I can use memcpy for my purposes (I need to understanding it without using extraneous functions). Sorry :(

Comment: sure, strcpy would be better for string handler.

Comment: you don't need `memcpy(...)` you can just use `strcpy(final[counter], foo)`

Comment: also, why are you `memset`ing? `foo` to `0`?

Comment: I'm not sure if the fscanf can add '\0' after get the string.
prevent the following example, first time we get string 
  foo = "abcdef";
andd the following is 
  foo = "ab"